# NAS not connecting after server name change

Tags: 22.04, nas

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04. After a NAS server name change it won't connect. I'm guessing I need to clear out the cache? If so how do I do that? I don't connect by name, I connect via IP address. Error I get is this when trying "`sudo mount -a~":

```
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you read `man mount.cifs`? Did you look at the logs with `dmesg` (or the more modern `journalctl`)? Did you look at your `/etc/fstab`? What does `host newservername` show? Please [edit] your Question to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by both current and future readers (who have better answers).  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Help us help you.